# Recreate or fix autotrace?

Tags: inkscape

I have this very simple bitmap:

[image]

My intention is to create a nice SVG from this.

Although I traced it with InkScape, but it created too many points and I would like to know how can I draw this from scratch with using basic tools only: circle, and Bezier curves and lines.

[image]

I am at this point:

[image]

But I have no idea on how can I create symmetrical and correct curves for the sides.

Comment: I would recreate it because it would take longer to fix an auto trace than it would to redraw it. Should only take a couple of minutes. [see video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CE8vPrMwJ7g).

Comment: Wow, amazingly easy! @52s: how did you add the new node to X of circle and line? By eye only, or there is some shortcut to match it exactly center?

Comment: Yes I just added the nodes by eye. Snapping to the centre guide (blue line). Shortcut for stretching selected nodes symmetrically is the Shift key. To constrain a circle and draw from the centre use Shift+Ctrl,

Answer (score 4):

I guess you expect how to draw the frame as a simple curve.

You get it symmetric if you draw only a half of it, duplicate, flip the copy and join the halves. The rounded corners look actually complex, but you get probably an acceptable (although not an exact) result easily if you use the minimum amount of nodes.

An example:

[image]

In the left a path is made by clicking with the Bezier tool (a.k.a. the pen). Start from the middle in the bottom and hold Ctrl to get the 2nd node at the same y-coordinate.

In the right: Drag the curved segments to the right curvature with the node tool. You can also move the nodes and handles if needed, but I only pushed the curve itself.

I used at first a narrow stroke to see easily its place. Change the stroke width.  Then duplicate (=Ctrl+D ) and flip the duplicate. Move it to the right place. It snaps, if you have all point snaps ON. Join the halves and remove the bottom midpoint.

[image]

BTW consider this as an example of manual tracing and how important it is to keep the node count low if one wants to keep the control. For a beginner it's very difficult  to  resist the urge to insert too many nodes.

**ADD:** Mr. Billy Kerr has inserted a comment which reminds path effect Fillet/Chamfer. Make the initial path which has only 4 nodes and insert that path effect. You can adjust the curve with the node tool like above except the curve stays circular with the typed radius. It works so well that you can as well start with the final stroke width.

The arcs (=fillets) seem to have the same radius, so there's no need to split the curve more.

You can make the effect permanent by applying Path > Object to Path. It makes the path free for other edits.

[image]

Comment: Inkscape now has a Corner (Fillet/Chamfer) Live Path Effect that works really well for rounded corners.

Comment: "Start from the middle in the bottom and hold Ctrl to get the 2nd node at the same y-coordinate" that's nice, but how can I get the 3rd and 4th node? Just purely clicking by eye?

Comment: So, how can I make symmetrical the 3rd and 4th node, wihtout applying heavy sin cos calcualtions? :)

Comment: I left-clicked with the Bezier tool on your image with no calculations at the points where the curve seems to change to straight line. Use high zoom in to see it. This method is tracing done visually, not anything exact.. Automatic tracing generates a result which is by Inkscape's own criteria optimal, but you have already rejected it.